# Putting the value of a variable into a table in R Markdown, rather than it's name

Tags: r, r-markdown

> Edited for clarity:
>
> Currently in R Markdown when I enter a variable like *"u_F"* into a cell
> in a Table, when I then knit the R Markdown file it will produce a Table
> that has *"u_F"* written in the cell. I would like it to instead produce a Table
> with the **value that u_F is equal to** written in the cell.

I'm working in R Markdown. I'd like to reproduce the attached table 4 from:

> Goldstein, D. A., Chen, Q., Ayer, T., Howard, D. H., Lipscomb, J.,
> Harvey, R. D., ... & Flowers, C. R. (2014). Cost effectiveness
> analysis of pharmacokinetically-guided 5-fluorouracil in FOLFOX
> chemotherapy for metastatic colorectal cancer. Clinical colorectal
> cancer, 13(4), 219-225.

But instead of having to enter the parameter values manually (i.e., "Value" = 1, "Minimum" = 0.80, "Maximum" = 1.20) I would like to just enter the parameter names and have R take these to fill in these values. Could someone show me how to do this please?

```
u_F <- 1
Maximum_u_F <- u_F + 0.20*u_F
Minimum_u_F <- u_F - 0.20*u_F

Variable | Value | Minimum     | Maximum     |  Reference      | Distribution

Utility | u_F    | Minimum_u_F | Maximum_u_F |  Smith, et al., | Gamma
```

[Table I am trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMNbF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're going for, but you execute R code inline using

```
`r <code>`
```

So putting this in your .Rmd

```
Variable| Value | Minimum | Maximum | Reference | Distribution |
--------|-------|---------|---------|-----------|--------------|
 Utility| `r u_F` | `r Minimum_u_F` | `r Maximum_u_F` | Smith, et al., | $\gamma$ |
```

will produce this:

[image]